Numerical check of rules of differentiation
in calculus there are some useful and proved rules for differentiation of functions, which allow to derive derivaties of complex matrix-valued functions (e.g., see matrix cookbook). I am curious how to numerically "verify" such rules or how to perform sanity checks on own derivations. More precisely, how to verify the "approximate equality" of the left and right side of, e.g., the following rules which hold for all $x$ or $\mathbf{x}$ of differentiable functions?
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^{T})\mathbf{x}\\
&\frac{d}{dx}f(x)g(x) = f^{\prime}(x)g(x)+f(x)g^{\prime}(x)
\end{align}
By "approximate equality" I mean that numerically both sides will not be equal, because by definition of the derivative
\begin{equation}
f^{\prime}(x) = \underset{\mathrm{d}x\rightarrow 0}{\lim}\,\frac{f(x+\mathrm{d}x)-f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
\end{equation}
$\mathrm{d}x$ is lower-bounded by machine precision, i.e., there is no number between 0 and eps.
Thank you very much for your help.

Even if you use a library that has numbers less than machine epsilon (which can be done in software), you still can check only a finite number of examples, so there will be some value of $dx$ such that you never test a smaller value. In any case, for a numeric verification you need to pick particular numbers and you will examine only a limited number of very specific cases. But the exercise could still be valuable for understanding. What have you tried?

There are higher order method to get the derivative with higher accuracy, see the proper section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

For sanity checks of complicated expressions it is imho more important to test many examples than try to push the precision down below machine precision. When you integrate or differentiate "by hand" and make an error there it will usually be shown quickly by the first few numerical examples.
